# Confirmation Dialog in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, dialog, confirmation

I'm building a Zend Application using doctrine repository classes to update, delete and insert data to the DB. These repositories are called from controller actions and they do exactly what they supposed to do. However, I'd like to add some confirmation dialogs to the application, so for example, if a user wants to edit or delete an item, a Confirm Edit or Delete dialog must first be opened and the data will be edited or deleted depending on what the user selects. Here's an example of some action code for updating a staff members details after the user has clicked on a zend form submit button.

```
public function updatestaffAction()
{        
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
            $values = $form->getValues();
            $user = $this->entityManager->find('\PTS\Entity\Staff', $values['staff_number']);
            $staffValues = array('staff_number' =>  $values['staff_number'],
                                 'title'        =>  $values['title'],
                                 'first_name'   =>  $values['first_name'],
                                 'last_name'    =>  $values['last_name'],
                                 'telephone'    =>  $values['telephone'],
                                 'cellphone'    =>  $values['cellphone'],
                                 'fax'          =>  $values['fax'],
                                 'email'        =>  $values['email'],
                                 'job_title'    =>  $values['job_title']);

            $this->staffRepository->saveStaff($staffValues);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }
    }
```

The staff repository saveStaff method simply creates a new Staff object and persists that object if the staff member doesn't exists, or merges the new data if it's an existing staff member as is the case for the update code above.

So my question is, how can I change the action to only save the data once the user has clicked the yes button in a confirmation dialog. BTW, the dialog can be either a JQuery or Dojo dialog box.

Comment: Do a JQuery dialog confirmation and call the controller junction using an Ajax `post`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not really sure how I should do that. My controller action also creates a zend form which is displayed using a viewscript decorator pattern. The code above is executed when the user clicks on the forms submit button. Should I not use a submit button but rather an ordinary button which calls the dialog event and if so, how do I then call the controller action and submit the form data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create form's submit button, set js code:

```
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('delete');

$submit->setAttrib(
'onclick', 
'if (confirm("Are you sure?")) { document.form.submit(); } return false;'
);
```

Or, if you want to set dialogbox on link (if you don't have submit form):

```
onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { document.location = this.href; } return false;"
```

Code for showDialog:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Are you sure": function() {
                                    // PUT your code for OK button, for eg.
                                    document.form.submit();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});`
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, and I've actually figured this out, but what i'd actually like to use a custom jquery or dojo dialog box instead. I can add an onclick attribute to the submit button or even an onsubmit attribute to the form which calls a showDialog function that displays the dialog window, but I can't figure out how to get the result from that dialog window. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thx, I used the second option like this way :

```
<a href="<?=$this->url('skill', array('action'=>'delete', 'id' => $skill->getId()))?>" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { document.location = this.href; } return false;">Delete</a>
```

and it's worked :)